# Python 2.7 : exe file created from pyinstaller doesnt work

Tags: python, windows, module, exe, pyinstaller

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/making-an-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-script-using-pyinstaller-d1df9170e263) to create my **run.exe** file using pyinstaller. I got my exe file in dist folder as expected without any error. But when i double click on the exe file, nothing happens. When i run the exe file from command prompt I get below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\PySimpleGUI27\PySimpleGUI27.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 459, in install_aliases
ImportError: No module named UserList
[16016] Failed to execute script run
```

I dont understand this error. I dont have any module name **Userlist** in my script. Below is my script:

```
import PySimpleGUI27 as sg
import parse

layout = [               
    [sg.Text('A2L File', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_a2l_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("A2L File", "*.a2l"),))],
    [sg.Text('Signals Lexicon', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_sigLex_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel File", "*.xlsx"),))],
    [sg.Text('Parameters Lexicon', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('',key='_parLex_'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel File", "*.xlsx"),))],
    [sg.Text('Module Name', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),      
     sg.InputText('X',key='_module_'), sg.FolderBrowse()],           
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()],
    [sg.Output(size=(60, 20))]  
]
window = sg.Window('A2L Parser', default_element_size=(40, 1)).Layout(layout)

values_dict={}
while True:
    button, values_dict = window.Read()
    if button=="Cancel" or button is None:
        break
    elif button=='Submit' and (not any(value == '' for value in values_dict.values())):   
        parse.parser(values_dict['_a2l_'], values_dict['_sigLex_'], values_dict['_parLex_'],window)

    else:
        sg.Popup("Please select files")  

window.Close()
```

This script works when I run it from Visual code so there is no error in the script. In this script I am importing my own script **parse**. 
Can someone please explain what is the issue with the exe file?

**Update** :  I found out that I will have to add these missing modules in my script. But after adding each module i get an error of another missing module. Is there a way to find all the missing modules in one go?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, here is the workaround:

1. Use any text editor to open this `site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py` file
2. Line 459 should be "__import__(oldmodname)" and in function "install_aliases()"
3. Just add below lines before "__import__(oldmodname)":

```
    if 0:
        import UserList
        import UserString
        import UserDict
        import itertools
        import collections
        import future.backports.misc
        import commands
        import base64
        import __buildin__
        import math
        import reprlib
        import functools
        import re
        import subprocess
```

4. Save and close this file. Then try again.

The reason why do we add above lines, please refers to https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2820

This workaround works for me. And if you feel the code snippet better to insert to other location, please adjust by yourself.